# When inheriting a Base class privately, can I declare the Base classes Basse class public?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance

I have a class "SuperBase" with public methods and a class "Base", that derives from SuperBase, also with public methods. I cannot alter these, as they come from an external project.

I want my own class "Derived" to inherit privately from Base, but still keep SuperBase public.

External Code (cannot be changed):

```
class SuperBase
{
public:
   void printSuperBase() const
   {
      std::cout << "Super Base Class\n";
   }
};

class Base : public SuperBase
{
public:
   void print() const
   {
      std::cout << "Base Class\n";
   }
};
```

My own code (can be changed):

```
class Derived: private Base
{
public:
   void print() const
   {
      std::cout << "Derived Class\n";
   }
};

void function(SuperBase const& sb)
{
   sb.printSuperBase();
}


int main() 
{
   Derived D{};
   D.print();    //prints "Derived Class\n"
   function(D);  //cannot access SuperBase, as Base was included privately
}
```

Note that I cannot override any of the Base class methods, as they are not declared virtual.

Including both, Base and SuperBase does not work as this makes SuperBase ambiguous.

```
class Derived: private Base, public SuperBase
{
public:
   void print() const
   {
      std::cout << "Derived Class\n";
   }
};

void function(SuperBase const& sb)
{
   sb.printSuperBase();
}


int main() 
{
   Derived D{};
   D.print();    //prints "Derived Class\n"
   function(D);  //base class SuperBase is ambiguous
}
```

Including Base publicly and declaring it's methods as private does not work either, as I now can pass Derived to functions using Base, that can access all privately declared methods

```
class Derived: public Base
{
public:
   void print() const
   {
      std::cout << "Derived Class\n";
   }
private:
   using Base::print; //declare base method private to make it inaccessible
};

void function2(Base const& b)
{
   b.print();          //prints "Base Class\n", but shall be inaccessible instead.
   b.printSuperBase();
}


int main() 
{
   Derived D{};
   D.print();    //prints "Derived Class\n"
   function2(D); //D gets passed as Base class, but shall not be allowed
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could not actually derive from Base or SuperBase at all but rather use composition and cast operators:

```
class Derived
{
private:
    Base mBase;

public:
   void print() const
   {
      std::cout << "Derived Class\n";
   }

    operator SuperBase const&() const
    {
        return mBase;
    }

    operator SuperBase&()
    {
        return mBase;
    }
};
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bnsY4e5Wz

Comment: Thank you, this works exactly like I wanted it. I was not away that you could declare operators on objects of other classes

Comment: @GulaschLulatsch It's a simple cast operator for `Derived` to another type, same as `operator bool() const` would be.

Comment: @ypnos I see, i somehow assumed, as `bool` is not a class, that this was a special typename cast that would not be possible for other classes. I was clearly wrong. Thanks for your help

Comment: Terminology: these are **conversion** operators, not a cast operators. They will be used whenever they provide an appropriate conversion, not just when there is a cast.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the answer is no.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33287197)

Comment: @Burak - "No" is an answer. It explicitly answers the question "... can I...?"

Comment: @WaiHaLee The question is not a dumb *is it possible* question. There is an external untouched code and there is a purpose to be satisfied. The problem *can* be solved with a method but not as OP suggested. This post should have been a comment.

Comment: I disagree, Burak. The question as stated is answered in full. The conversion operator trick in the other answer is very nice and I learned something new. But it does not fulfill the stated requirement of an inheritance chain. E.g., even if enhanced with pointer conversions, it would fail as soon as some code were to dynamic-cast back to `Derived`. It is also something that would be forbidden in many environments (being seen a dangerous misuse of conversion operators). It is great that it works for OP (for now), but that cannot be anticipated from how the question is posed.

Answer (score 0):

That heavily depends on whether you depend in type conformance of `Derived` to `Base`, what other parts you may want to encompass in your class and how `Base` itself shadows/overrides `SuperBase` members, but you may just wrap `Base` object privately and forward all function calls however you want:

```cpp
class Derived: public SuperBase
{
    Base imp;
public:
   void print() const
   {
      std::cout << "Derived Class\n";
   }
};
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I have currently started doing but my Base class has a lot of methods I need to shadow...

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, unless `SuperBase` is a `virtual` base of `Base`.

You could introduce a friend function `function` though that applies the necessary cast to call `function`:

```
void function(SuperBase const& sb);

class Derived : private Base
{
public:
    void print() const
    {
        std::cout << "Derived Class\n";
    }

    /**
     * Introduce a overload of function at namespace scope that has access to the conversion to SuperBase
     */
    friend void function(Derived const& derived)
    {
        function(static_cast<SuperBase const&>(derived));
    }
};

void function(SuperBase const& sb)
{
    sb.printSuperBase();
}
```